# What is the difference between primitive data type vs an non primitive data type(apple defined data type)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, primitive-types, nsinteger

What's the basic difference between the two..? it would be nice if can someone explain using the example of NSInteger and NSNumber.. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main difference is related to where they stay in the memory, objects are stored in the heap while value type are stored directly in the Stack ...

**heap** : is an area of memory used for dynamic memory allocation.

**stack** : is the section of memory that is allocated for automatic variables within functions. Data is stored in stack using the Last In First Out (LIFO) method.

About NSInteger and NSNumber :

*NSInteger is nothing more than a synonym for a long integer, while NSNumber is an Objective-C class, a subclass of NSValue to be specific.*

Comment: Not main difference and in some cases not true at all..  NSInteger *i = malloc(sizeof(NSInteger)); NSString *constString = @"constString"; - quite opposite to what you said.

Comment: Of course you can force a value type to stay on the heap, but it is not the default behavior ... In your example you are manually allocating memory and declaring a pointer to an NSInteger , you are not using the value type, but the pointer to access a memory address ...

Comment: 1) Memory type is still not the main difference of objects and Plain old data types. 2) In many languages for example C++ objects can be allocated in stack. And it's default behavior there. 3) In some cases Objective-C objects can be allocated in stack.

Comment: This is not a particularly useful distinction to draw. A primitive-typed ivar will be on the heap, with the object that holds it.

Answer (score 8):

object is : member data + function operating on the data

so, primitive data type is just data, no method directly related to it.

object is something like a module, include the data and function (method here).

NSInteger is primitive data type.
NSNumber is object, it's member data maybe NSInteger.

Answer (score 2):

Primitive data types store a direct value, for example NSInteger stores an integer value (either a 32 bit Integer, or a 64 bit Integer depending on the compiled architecture), Objects are an instance of a class, with methods, properties, etc.

In order to get an NSInteger from an NSNumber, you would use

```
[aNumber intValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Primitive data types are used for storing fundamental types of data, such as strings, integers, and real numbers. So when you declare a value type variable, the compiler sets aside, or allocates, a chunk of memory that is big enough for that variable. The way reference types work is different. When you are working with a reference type, you are using two things, an object that is created in memory and a variable that references to the object. The variable does not hold an actual piece of data with which your program will work. Instead it holds a special value known as a reference, which links the variable to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data type is just a data while object type is know as reference type.
Which is a class which have two behavior data member and member function.