# Objective-C: why int, double, char, etc.. does not require pointers to create an object from them

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I'm new in objective-C and I have a question about pointers

I know when I want to store an address instead of a value I use pointers

and in order to get an address, I have to use the **&variableName**

in objective-C, in order to make an object, I have to do the following:

```
ClassName *theObject = [[ClassName alloc] init];
```

which means I'm storing the address of **ClassName** in the object **theObject**

which is the same idea as:

```
ClassName *theObject = &ClassName; //(Correct me if i'm wrong please);
```

but my question is when I make an object of int, float, double, char
I don't create the object as explained above, the only thing I do is:

```
int object = 7;
```

why is it different in int, double, char, etc... ? they are not interfaces or what?

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031732/what-is-the-difference-between-primitive-data-type-vs-an-non-primitive-data-type

Comment: You can work with pointers at int, double and char. Just add `*`. `*` - is mark that this is pointer. Even pointers at pointers are exists. There is opposite restriction: you can't create `NSObject`s as values.

Comment: See [Understanding pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746683/understanding-pointers)

Comment: See [When to and when not to use pointers in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074369/when-to-and-when-not-to-use-pointers-in-objective-c)

Comment: See [need of pointer objects in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992127/need-of-pointer-objects-in-objective-c)

Comment: I still see people memorizing instead of understanding, my question was tooooo clear but the answers you referred too are too general I already know it, thanks I don't need your answer